# How to upload Image AWSS3 TransferManager upload Request objective c?

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services

I am working on an app in which I need to upload image using AWSS3. Below is my code. However I am getting error something about pool id not found. I am not sure whats going, Do I need to add anything more.

This is the error getting

Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=ResourceNotFoundException, message=IdentityPool 'ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxx' not found

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@""];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

// get the image from a UIImageView that is displaying the selected Image

// create a local image that we can use to upload to s3
NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

// once the image is saved we can use the path to create a local fileurl
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

// next we set up the S3 upload request manager
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *_uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
// set the bucket
_uploadRequest.bucket = @"chatify";
// I want this image to be public to anyone to view it so I'm setting it to Public Read
_uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead;
// set the image's name that will be used on the s3 server. I am also creating a folder to place the image in
_uploadRequest.key = @"ios/image.png";
// set the content type
_uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
// we will track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
_uploadRequest.body = url;

__weak ClaimViewController *weakSelf = self;

_uploadRequest.uploadProgress =^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend){
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        weakSelf.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent;
        weakSelf.filesize = totalBytesExpectedToSend;
        [weakSelf update];

    });
};

// now the upload request is set up we can creat the transfermanger, the credentials are already set up in the app delegate
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
// start the upload
[[transferManager upload:_uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

    // once the uploadmanager finishes check if there were any errors
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", task.error);
    }else{// if there aren't any then the image is uploaded!
        // this is the url of the image we just uploaded
        NSLog(@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-demo-objectivec/foldername/image.png");
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi @kashif the error clear says that you need to add the pool id

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@""];
```

but in the Above code you just pass the Black in identityPoolId

Here's also another method to which provide Credential

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:@"AccessKey"  secretKey :@"secretKey"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2
                                                                         credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Comment: Its just for posting, i remove Pool id, else i have already pass pool id previosly

Comment: i just updated my answer please try with second solution

Comment: @Kashif May be You need to Check you IAM policy because You don't authenticate access

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of your Cognito Identity Pool being deleted from your account or you setting the region incorrectly. Your region should be set to 
`AWSRegionAPNorthEast1` based on what I see in the posted code.

Thanks,
Rohan